# Bagging of xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, bagging, gradient

The extreme-gradient boosting algorithm seems to be widely applied these days. I often have the feeling that boosted models tend to overfit. I know that there are parameters in the algorithm to prevent this. Sticking to the [documentation here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md) the parameters `subsample` and `colsample_bytree` could (among others) prevent overfitting. But they do not serve for the same purpose as bagging xgboosted models would - right?

My question: would you apply bagging on top of xgboost to reduce the variance of the fit?

So far the question is statistical and I dare to add a code detail: in case bagging makes sense I would be happy about example code using the R package `caret`.

EDIT after the remark: if we rely on the parameters only to control the overfit, then how can we design the cross-validation best? I have approx. 6000 data points and apply 5-fold x-validation. What could improve the out-of-sample performance: going to something like 10-fold x-validation or doing repeated 5-fold x-validation? Just to mention: I use the package `cartet` where such strategies are implemented.

Comment: Just a comment.  You didn't mention the learning rate of boosted models explicitly, which is extremely important in preventing over-fitting.

Comment: Could work, but ensembles of ensembles can grow quite big. It may be more efficient to find a appropriate set of training parameters not leading to over fitting for a given data set.

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling please see my edit.

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1758-2946-6-10
If I were to publish some A-grade ML model I would go for the proposed **Algorithm 3: repeated grid-search cross-validation for
variable selection and parameter tuning**. I don't use `caret` that much (I should). As I remember `caret` do not provide a outer cross-validation for a grid-search. I would feel comfortable by wrapping a `caret grid search` in a outer 5 or 10fold-CV loop and check if each fold optimal paramters close to the same. For final model, pick the typical parameter set from folds and use outer CV as error estimation.

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling  I opened up a discussion about overfitting here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204489/discussion-about-overfit-in-xgboost in case you want to join.

Comment: There was an article about that in JMLR by Tuv, Borisov, Runger and Torkkola on this.  https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume10/tuv09a/tuv09a.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The bag in bagging is about aggregation.  If you have k CART models then for an input you get k candidate answers.  How do you reduce that to a single value.  The aggregation does that.  It is often a measure of central tendency like the mean or mode.

In order to aggregate, you would need multiple outputs.  The gradient boosted machine (gbm) as in XGboost, is a series ensemble, not  parallel one.  This means that it lines them all up in a bucket brigade, and all the learners (but front and back) take the output of one, and give it to the next one).  The final output is the same structure as a CART model - a single output.  There is no bootstrapping to be done on a single element.

Comment: Nice to see a good answer to a long-unanswered question (+1). The serial nature of gradient boosted machines is why slow learning at each step is so important to avoid the overfitting noted by the OP.

Comment: Slow learning does several good things.  There isn't momentum, so the best resolving power of the learner is governed by the single learning rate.

Comment: You can do bagging of several XGBoost/GBM models, each of which is considered a black box rather than an ensemble. The question is whether this is going to be efficient, and the answer is probably no (not enough randomisation for efficient variance reduction).